# Get Azure Web App name in code

Tags: azure, web-applications, azure-web-app-service

Is there any way to obtain the name of the web app from within code. i.e. if I have deployed my app to a web app called my-webapp-dev-ne I need to be able to get this name in code. The reason I cannot add it to an app config file or any other method is that the same app can be deployed to multiple places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would set this as a configuration in your web.config - for example:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="sitename" value="my-webapp-dev-ne" />
  </appSettings>
```

Answer (score 9):

Adding to Rick's answer, you can find more informative environment settings [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-runtime-environment#website-environment-variables)

- `WEBSITE_SKU` - The sku of the site (Possible values: Free, Shared, Basic, Standard).
- `WEBSITE_COMPUTE_MODE` - Specifies whether website is on a dedicated or shared VM/s (Possible values: Shared, Dedicated).
- `WEBSITE_SITE_MODE` - The mode for the site (can be Limited for a free site, Basic for a shared site or empty for a standard site).
- `WEBSITE_HOSTNAME` - The Azure Website's primary host name for the site (For example: site.azurewebsites.net). Note that custom hostnames are not accounted for here.
- `WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID` - The id representing the VM that the site is running on (If site runs on multiple instances, each instance will have a different id).
- `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` - The default node version this website is using.
- `WEBSOCKET_CONCURRENT_REQUEST_LIMIT` - The limit for websocket's concurrent requests.

Answer (score 4):

The web app environment provides an environment variable called **WEBSITE_SITE_NAME** that contains the name.  You can access it from C# code like this.

```
var siteName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_SITE_NAME");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this if you installed the **Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager** nuget.

```
var siteName = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("WEBSITE_SITE_NAME");
```

Reference:
[CloudConfigurationManager Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.cloudconfigurationmanager.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)